# Discord.py Bot Autodelete

Tags: discord.py, bots, auto-delete

Im new to python (i learned the basics at a school course),
and for the moment im trying to create simple bots for my discord server.
And for the moment, the bot i really want, is an autodelete bot so that i can say, (for example) delete every message in the ...Channel after 24h. because i really dont wanna do that manually.
I know there are a few good bots that do that,
but for example **MEE6** wants me to buy Premium to use the funktion.The other reason why i dont want to use any finished bot is that i really want to understand and learn the code,
i watched many tutorials and tried to put the parts of the scripts that i understood together, but it did not work. I also didnt find a tutorial which explained it to me so that i understood, so now im here and hope that im going to understand it.
I hope there are some ppl to help me. :)

Thanks
**-Yami.Code**

```
@bot.event()
async def on_ready(ctx):
    while requirement == 1:
        await ctx.channel.purge
        time.sleep(20)
```

#the Error is:

```
line 11, in <module>
    @bot.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't call `bot.event` (remove the parenthesis),
2. `time.sleep` is a blocking call, use `asyncio.sleep` instead ([What does "blocking" mean](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean))
3. `on_ready` doens't take `ctx` as an argument, if you want to send a message to a channel you should get the channel object first, and then use the `send` method
4. You're missing a parenthesis in your `channel.purge` method...

```py
import asyncio # if you haven't already

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # replace `channel_id` with an actual channel ID
    while requirement == 1:
        await channel.purge(limit=x) # change `x` accordingly...
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
```

Comment: #then it says:  __Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(privat)", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'__

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer, a small note: you should really learn more python before diving into discord.py, 5 lines and 4 errors...

Comment: Ok im going to learn on it more before doing hard things, but it is sends the same error again.

Comment: Sorry my bad, take a look at the edit now. PS you have to change `channel_id` and `x` in the code

Comment: but i dont want a limit, or do i have to set any limit? (i changed the channel id and the x before)

Comment: You cannot, the max messages you can bulk delete is 100

Comment: so would i have to run the code more than one time to delete everything in a channel with more than a hundred messages

Comment: sadly yes, discord doesn't allow us to bulk delete more than 100 messages. Remember to accept the answer if it helped though (tick on the left upper side of the answer)

Comment: i know you said i should learn more before doing hard things like that, but is there maybe some way to check for messages? cause if there is, i could try to delete as long as there are messages in the channel.

Comment: You can use [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history), it will throw an error when there's no more messages to fetch, you can use that to know when to stop deleting, though you're gonna get massive ratelimit issues and you may get temporarily (or even permanently) banned from the discord API.